# Can a program such as AutoHotkey be implemented in a browser(as an add-on) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, accessibility, autohotkey

The main use of AutoHotkey I'm thinking of is to let you define phrase-shortcuts, like typing "tyvm" would yield "thank you very much" - is JavaScript fast enough and capable enough to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say that is the main use of autohotkey, but that is neither here nor there,

In a word, yes, yes it is fast enough, otherwise inputs would not be able to have keydown/keyup events.

What makes you think javascript is slow?

Comment: Well I guess because javascript is interpreted, a bit far from the "metal" if you will. Thank You!

Comment: Javascript is fast enough to [decode H.264 video on conventional hardware](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway). Expanding text based on shortcut's is trivial on the CPU by comparison

Answer (score 2):

Your question wasn't exactly clear to if you were only looking for AutoHotkey, so I though I would state "YES" and support that by reference to another implementation: [http://keithcirkel.co.uk/jwerty/](https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/) in JavaScript that handles keyboard events.